# Clarification of Go's smtp.PlainAuth

Tags: go, smtp

We have this `PlainAuth` function:

`func PlainAuth(identity, username, password, host string) Auth`

The documentation states the following:

> PlainAuth returns an Auth that implements the PLAIN authentication
> mechanism as defined in RFC 4616. The returned Auth uses the given
> username and password to authenticate to host and act as identity.
> Usually identity should be the empty string, to act as username.

For me, this is pretty confusing. What is actually the identity
and what acts as username?

What is really happening when we put an empty string as the first
parameter and what other options can we put there?

Comment: The link helped clarify the identity a bit.